# css specificity - have nothing for more specific class

Tags: html, css

Say I have the following css:

```
  .InfoTable-main-table tbody tr td:before{
    background: #222;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    padding: .25em .5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
  }
```

but I want a more specific css to have none of that i.e.

```
  .InfoTable-main-table tbody tr td.extra:before{

  }
```

However, the previous css still applies. Is there a way to disregard the more general css or will I have to relegate to just applying it to a specific class instead?

Comment: Specificity only affects certain styles. If a style appears in both selectors, the selector with more specificity has that style applied.

Comment: Clarifying: so you want to apply the first style block to table cells (td) that do *not* have the `.extra` class? Have you come across the `:not()` selector before? `.InfoTable-main-table tbody tr td:not(.extra):before` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: @stealththeninja yeah, but I was just wondering if there was a way, incase I want to add css to it later, but for now I just want it blank. Just more of a curious question.

Comment: For `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, just set `content:none`. No box will be created and the other properties will be irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're asking for a set of styles applied to table cells *without* the 'extra' class and styles *with* the class, the `:not()` selector seems like a good fit:

```
.InfoTable-main-table tbody tr td:not(.extra):before{
  background: #222;
  ...
}

.InfoTable-main-table tbody tr td.extra:before{

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use !important after propertive css like this:

```
 .InfoTable-main-table tbody tr td.extra:before{
      left: 100px!important;
  }
```